# How to get GoogleMap object from a SupportMapFragment created in an XML? API level 8

Tags: android, android-layout, fragment

I'm trying to get the `GoogleMap` object from the `SupportMapFragment` object. Because I want this work on API level 8 too, solution like `findFragmentById` wont work for me..

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:background="#fff"
   android:id="@+id/map_view"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
      map:cameraZoom="11"
      map:cameraTargetLat="32.1275701"
      map:cameraTargetLng="34.7983432"
      map:uiZoomControls="false"/>

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"    
        android:contentDescription="@string/back"    
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="returnToMain"
        android:background="@drawable/return_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE:**

The Java code:

```
public void category(View v){
    if(isNetworkAvailable()){
        if(viewMap==null){
            setContentView(R.layout.map_view);
            viewMap=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.map_view);
            Fragment ssmf=getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapObject=((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            mapObject.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(32.1275701, 34.7983432))
            .title("Hello world"));
        }
        else{
            setContentView(viewMap);
        }
    }
}
```

I got this error:

Cannot cast form `Fragment` to `SupportMapFragment`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because I want this work on API level 8 too, solution like findFragmentById wont work for me.

Yes, it will. From your `FragmentActivity`, after you inflate the above layout, call `findFragmentById(R.id.map)`, cast the result to a `SupportMapFragment`, and call `getMap()` on that to retrieve your `GoogleMap` object.

Comment: @IvanKovac: You have the wrong `Fragment` import. You need the `support.v4` version, not `android.app.Fragment`.

Comment: Yes, I figure it out myself. But your answer gave me a hint definitely.. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use getSupportFragmentManager() when you use, SupportFragments.